# Converting a received POST request in Node to a Javascript object

Tags: javascript, node.js, web

I'm sorry for the very basic question but I could not figure this out.  This is my first time writing a server.  Pretty much we have an iPhone app that consults the server I am writing by doing a POST request with JSON data.  When I receive this data, is this equivalent to an object in JavaScript?  When I have two objects in Javascript, assuming of the format:

```
var x = { major_id: 1234, minor_id: 5678};
var y = { major_id: 1234, minor_id: 5678};
```

Am I able to do:

```
if (x == y) {
    //do something
}
```

Or do I need to compare each element in the object individually?

Comment: You have to compare each element of the object individually to see if all properties are the same.  `==` compares to see if they are the same object, NOT that they are two separate objects with the same content.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for the response!  As far as receiving POST requests go, is the variable that I receive from the POST request a string, or an object, or what?  I am having trouble making the comparison because I'm not sure how to make the data I receive equivalent to the variables I have within the app.  Thanks!

Comment: You'd have to show us the code that sends the POST and the code that receives the POST for us to know what it is.  It is probably sent over the wire as a JSON string and then that may or may not be parsed into a javascript object depending upon your receiving code.  You can do a `console.log(typeof x)` and  `console.log(x)` on it to see what it is on the receiving end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you receive from POST. It is most probably stringified JSON, that you can transform into an object using : `JSON.parse(receivedString);`

Check the type of your variables using `typeof x`

Once both x and y have the same type, you can compare them as follows :

- if x AND y are JSON strings, use `x==y`
- if they are both objects, you need to compare parameters one by one. Some libraries abstract that for you. For example, you could use [Underscore.JS](http://underscorejs.org/#isEqual) method isEqual and do something like :

  ```
  var _ = require('underscore')
  var x = { major_id: 1234, minor_id: 5678};
  var y = { major_id: 1234, minor_id: 5678};
  if(_.isEqual(x, y)){
    //Do stuff
  }
  ```